# Running my Outlook add-in in OWA

Tags: outlook, ms-office, add-in, office-js

I've made an add-in for Outlook. It adds two command buttons to the ribbon which, when clicked open a task pane with a specific URL. This works fine in the desktop version of Outlook but I don't know how and if I can get this to work in the online version of Outlook. The MS documentation implies OWA supports add-ins but there are no explicit examples (manifests) I can find. When I go to outlook.office.com, click the options button and click "manage add-ins", the add-in is listed under "My add-ins", but there is only an "uninstall" button and no on/off toggle like I have with, for instance, the GIPHY add-in.

Am I missing something in my Manifest? (included below for completeness sake)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="MailApp" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0">
    <Id>1e38cb9a-2367-47b9-96b5-8b054dfdd293</Id>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>ProviderName</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="DisplayName"/>
    <Description DefaultValue="Description"/>
    <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:10084/officeAddIn/icon128.png"/>
    <SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://www.something.com" />
    <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
    </Hosts>
    <Requirements>
        <Sets>
            <Set Name="MailBox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
        </Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <FormSettings>
        <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
            <DesktopSettings>
                <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:10084/officeAddIn/app/home.html"/>
                <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
            </DesktopSettings>
        </Form>
    </FormSettings>
    <Permissions>ReadItem</Permissions>
    <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit"/>
    </Rule>

    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
        <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
                <DesktopFormFactor>
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                        <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                            <Group id="gv.store">
                                <Label resid="gv.label.store" />

                                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="gv.newasebtn">
                                    <Label resid="gv.label.newcase" />
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="gv.label.newcase" />
                                        <Description resid="gv.descr.newcase" />
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="gv.icon.16" />
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="gv.icon.32" />
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="gv.icon.80" />
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                        <SourceLocation resid="gv.url.new_case" />
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>

                                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="gv.existingcasebtn">
                                    <Label resid="gv.label.existingcase" />
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="gv.label.existingcase" />
                                        <Description resid="gv.descr.existingcase" />
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="gv.icon.16" />
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="gv.icon.32" />
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="gv.icon.80" />
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                        <SourceLocation resid="gv.url.existing_case" />
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
                            </Group>
                        </OfficeTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>
                </DesktopFormFactor>
            </Host>
        </Hosts>

        <Resources>
            <bt:Images>
                <bt:Image id="gv.icon.16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:10084/officeAddIn/icon16.png" />
                <bt:Image id="gv.icon.32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:10084/officeAddIn/icon32.png" />
                <bt:Image id="gv.icon.80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:10084/officeAddIn/icon80.png" />
            </bt:Images>
            <bt:Urls>
                <bt:Url id="gv.url.home" DefaultValue="https://localhost:10084/officeAddIn/app/home.html?gvhost=outlook" />
                <bt:Url id="gv.url.new_case" DefaultValue="https://localhost:10084/officeAddIn/app/new_case.html?gvhost=outlook" />
                <bt:Url id="gv.url.existing_case" DefaultValue="https://localhost:10084/officeAddIn/app/existing_case.html?gvhost=outlook" />
            </bt:Urls>
            <bt:ShortStrings>
                <bt:String id="gv.label.store" DefaultValue="Opslaan in" />
                <bt:String id="gv.label.home" DefaultValue="Home" />
                <bt:String id="gv.label.newcase" DefaultValue="Nieuw" />
                <bt:String id="gv.label.existingcase" DefaultValue="Bestaand" />
            </bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:LongStrings>
                <bt:String id="gv.descr.newcase" DefaultValue="Nieuw" />
                <bt:String id="gv.descr.existingcase" DefaultValue="Bestaand" />
                <bt:String id="gv.descr.home" DefaultValue="Deze knop is uitsluitend bedoeld voor test doeleinden." />
            </bt:LongStrings>
        </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: If you're looking for explicit examples, you can check out the manifest for Message Header Analyzer: https://github.com/stephenegriffin/MHA/blob/master/Manifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure since when, but OWA supports taskpane add-ins now. The button to open the taskpane add-on that normally shows in the ribbon (in Outlook desktop) now shows at the right top of the email viewing pane, next to the "like" and "reply (all)" buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest is missing the IconURL element and appears to have one or more URLs in SourceLocation elements that cannot be resolved.  Try validating it with the [Office App Compatibility Kit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46831).

I'm guessing it's one of the URLs in `<Resources><bt:Urls>`; are you sure new_case.thml and existing_case.html are valid files?

The only other thing I can see that may be wrong is this element: `<Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit"/>`

Your add-in is only activated for read mode so that Rule isn't required.  It's also weird that you can't turn on your add-in; are you saying there is no check box for your add-in in the Turned On column in the Manage Add-ins page?

Comment: Also note that add-in commands (aka ribbon buttons) aren't supported in OWA/Outlook Online.

Comment: I added the IconUrl but that didn't do much (other than, indeed, displaying the correct icon in the listing of my add-ins).
I guess those URL's couldn't be resolved because they point to localhost:10084. I have a webserver listening at that address here.
However, what I am starting to suspect is that OWA doesn't support task panels in the reading pane? I did manage to get an in-line button in my reading pane that, when clicked, opens an in-line iframe with my add-in. It works but it's a shame that it differs in functionality from the desktop version

Comment: Correct - only the inline type frames are supported in OWA, not the vertical Task Panes (which oddly ARE supported for compose emails, while the inline ones are not supported). Parity is promised "in the future"